# How to insert an ObservableCollection property to a local sqlite-net db?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a quick question about the sqlite-net library which can be found here : https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net.

The thing is I have no idea **how collections, and custom objects will be inserted into the database, and how do I convert them back when querying, if needed**.

Take this model for example:

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }
private string _name; // The name of the subject. i.e "Physics"
private ObservableCollection<Lesson> _lessons;
```

Comment: why not use ADO or EntityFramework ?

Comment: I don't know. It looks pretty simple and straight-forward... It's also been suggested quite a few times in relation to local databases/storage.

Comment: what as? 
ADO and EntityFramework .

Comment: And then what? how does it answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I've not used sqlite-net; rather, I spent some time simply reviewing the source code on the github link posted in the question.

From the first page on the [sqlite-net github](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) site, there are two bullet points that should help in some high level understanding:

> - Very simple methods for executing CRUD operations and queries safely (using parameters) and for retrieving the results of those
>     query in a strongly typed fashion

In other words, sqlite-net will work well with non-complex models; will probably work best with flattened models.

> - Works with your data model without forcing you to change your classes. (Contains a small reflection-driven ORM layer.)

In other words, sqlite-net will transform/map the result set of the SQL query to your model; again, will probably work best with flattened models.

Looking at the primary source code of [SQLite.cs](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs), there is an `InsertAll` method and a few overloads that will insert a collection.

When querying for data, you should be able to use the `Get<T>` method and the `Table<T>` method and there is also an `Query<T>` method you could take a look at as well. Each should map the results to the type parameter.

Finally, take a look at the [examples](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/tree/master/examples) and [tests](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/tree/master/tests) for a more in-depth look at using the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked quite a bit with SQLite-net in the past few months (including [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/using-sqlite-dot-net-in-mvvmcross) yesterday)

> how collections, and custom objects will be inserted into the database

I think the answer is they won't.

While it is a very capable database and ORM, SQLite-net is targeting lightweight mobile apps. Because of this lightweight focus, the classes used are generally very simple flattened objects like:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Lesson
{
    public int LessonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

If you then need to Join these back together and to handle insertion and deletion of related objects, then that's down to you - the app developer - to handle. There's no auto-tracking of related objects like there is in a larger, more complicated ORM stack.

In practice, I've not found this a problem. I find SQLite-net very useful in my mobile apps.